# How to call a extension file for a border of pitcure in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift3, border, layer

My code below is supposed to feature a customizable border for a photo taken. I originally had a border but it was not customizable. I saw this code online about a customizable border in a extension file (CALAYER). Its obviously to me I have to call the CALYAER function in my class file (x1ViewController) for the border to appear I just don't know how to do it.

```
import UIKit

extension CALayer {
func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer();

    switch edge {
    case UIRectEdge.top:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.bottom:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.frame.height - thickness, width:self.frame.width, height:thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.left:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.right:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height:self.frame.height)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

    self.addSublayer(border)
}


}



class x1ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var imageDisplay: UIImageView!
     var screenView: UIImageView!







@IBAction func camera(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self







       // imageDisplay.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1.0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        //imageDisplay.layer.cornerRadius = 1
       // imageDisplay.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       // imageDisplay.layer.borderWidth = 1


        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)}}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]!){
    imageDisplay.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    screenView = UIImageView()

    screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)




    let text = "#HAPPY"
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 125, y: 700, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 122)

    label.textColor = UIColor.blue
    label.alpha = 1.0
    label.text = text


    self.view.addSubview(screenView)
    self.view.addSubview(label)


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageDisplay.frame.size)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

}
@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved", message: "Image is in photo gallery", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okay)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



    let photo = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo!, nil, nil, nil)

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension adds that method to `CALayer`.  You can access a view's layer by using its `layer` property.

`myView.layer.addBorder(/* your arguments*/)`

Comment: So I would put myView.layer.addBorder(imageDisplay)? That is what the uiimageview that i need the border to be attached to. thanks.

Comment: No, if imageDisplay is the view you want to add a border to, then you would do something like `imageDisplay.layer.addBorder([.Top], UIColor.redColor(), 1.0)` It looks like you're using 2.x Swift syntax so this would look a little different with 3.0

Comment: This works perfect. The only thing is that it cuts off the image. How can I make the picture not be cropped and just be resized depending upon the customized border thickness? Thanks @Dima

Comment: You could "layer" views then (forgive the play on words). Instead of **imageView.layer.addborder**, put the imageView as a subview into a larger UIView. Then use **newView.layer.addBorder**.